# 504 DNS Lookup failed with domain-user, working fine with local user

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, dns-server

I just set up a DNS Server on my Windows Server 2012 R2 DC and joined my PC into this domain (test.local).

But now I a DNS error when trying to access an Web Application from another domain (eg. https://mail.test2.local/owa). What am I doing wrong? Everything is working fine when I switch back to the local Administrator

Traceroute and nslookup for mail.test2.local are giving me the same results for both scenarios

Comment: The `local` pseudo TLD should not be used with DNS since it's handled by mDNS. You should use a domain you own.

Comment: Wait so does tracert and nslookup function correctly for local machine user and domain user, or does it work for local machine user and fail for domain user?  That isn't exactly clear.  Are you getting a "DNS error" from your browser, or are you getting a DNS error from nslookup?

Answer (score 0):

For the OWA website you should always create an alias within Exchange for InternalURI and ExternalURI to point to your registered domain's name.

Please see [there](http://www.mustbegeek.com/configure-external-and-internal-url-in-exchange-2016/) for the step.

By dooing so it will force you to create a splitDNS setup, to host your registred domain internally, to point mail.myregistreddomain.com to your internal IP, while in the outside world the nameserver result will be your public IP for the same domain resolution.

That will allow you to use a real certificate on that server too in the end from a know certificate authority.